# What the best possible way to concatenate pandas column and count ? From a list of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have dataframe like this:

```
A     B     C    D     E      F
aa    bb    cc  dd    ee      ff
NA    ba    NA  da    ea      NA

list_col = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

So i just want to merge the columns which are in list only. Moreover i dont want NA values as merged..  is there any way? and the i need one more column which give the count (How many columns are merged as you can see in my desired output

I can calculate the "desired_col"  by this:

`df['desired_col'] = df[list_col].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)`

desired_output

```
 A     B     C    D     E      F         desired_col       desired_count
aa    bb    cc  dd    ee      ff          aa-bb-cc            3
NA    ba    NA  da    ea      NA             ba               1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another solution, the concatenation section is long though

```
df['desired_col'] = df.filter(list_col).fillna('').add('-').sum(axis=1).str.strip('-')
df['count'] = df.desired_col.str.split('-').str.len()
df

     A  B   C   D   E   F   desired_col count
0   aa  bb  cc  dd  ee  ff  aa-bb-cc    3
1   NaN ba  NaN da  ea  NaN ba          1
```

Comment: None removed NaNs consetutive in middle

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) for get number of `-` values:

```
list_col = ['A', 'B', 'C']

df['desired_col'] = df[list_col].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
df['desired_count'] = df['desired_col'].str.count('-') + 1
print (df)
     A   B    C   D   E    F desired_col  desired_count
0   aa  bb   cc  dd  ee   ff    aa-bb-cc              3
1  NaN  ba  NaN  da  ea  NaN          ba              1
```

Why is wrong @sammywemmy answer - it not remove missing values in middle of data:

```
list_col = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df['desired_col'] = df.filter(list_col).fillna('').add('-').sum(axis=1).str.strip('-')
df['count'] = df.desired_col.str.split('-').str.len()

print (df)
     A    B   C   D   E    F desired_col  count
0   aa  NaN NaN  dd  ee   ff     aa---dd      4
1  NaN   ba NaN  da  ea  NaN      ba--da      3
```

---

```
list_col = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df['desired_col'] = df[list_col].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
df['desired_count'] = df['desired_col'].str.count('-') + 1
print (df)
     A    B   C   D   E    F desired_col  desired_count
0   aa  NaN NaN  dd  ee   ff       aa-dd              2
1  NaN   ba NaN  da  ea  NaN       ba-da              2
```

Comment: @s_khan92 - `df['desired_col'] = df[list_col].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)` working well ?

Comment: @s_khan92 - hmm, so `dropna` remove missing values and `count` not remove them? It is weird, are you sure NaNs are removed?

Comment: Yes NaN are removed and its giving perfect output for the 'desired_col'

Comment: @s_khan92 - Or `df['desired_count'] = df['desired_col'].str.count('-')` ?

Comment: sammywemmy answer is working good. `df['count'] = df.desired_col.str.split('-').str.len()`

Comment: @s_khan92 - Check edit, answer is wrong, because not removed in midlle missing values, so count is also wrong

Comment: Yes true but i mainly needed for count because for "desired_col" i already answered in my question. :)

Comment: @s_khan92 - OK, it is up to you, `df['desired_count'] = df['desired_col'].str.count('-') + 1` is maybe better solution.